# undefined method `read_attributes' for a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is a code in a model:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def role
    read_attributes(:role).to_sym
  end

  def role= value
    write_attributes :role, value.to_s
  end
end
```

But I got next error:

```
undefined method read_attributes for MyModel:0x00000003014070
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because read_attributes is not a method. It is `read_attribute`.